# Posting a message in weechat starting with a slash

Tags: irc, weechat

In irssi, if someone was asking `how do I register my nickname?`, I could respond with `/ /msg nickserv help register` (and have the first `/<space>` be stripped from the message sent.

In weechat, this syntax doesn't work - is there a way to send out a message that starts with a slash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use double slash

`//msg nickserv help register`

Comment: This didn't work, I had to use "/say".

Comment: what version are you using? http://www.weechat.org/files/doc/stable/weechat_user.en.html#command_line_syntax

Answer (score 5):

Turns out you can do `/say /msg nickserv help register`, and it would do the right thing. `say` is, by default, aliased to `/msg *`.